# Getting Service Tag from Dell Machine using .net?

Tags: c#, vb.net, wmi

I've got a class that pulls model information (hardware info) 
for a local machine code is like so:

```
   Imports System.Management

Public Class clsWMI
    Private objOS As ManagementObjectSearcher
    Private objCS As ManagementObjectSearcher
    Private objMgmt As ManagementObject
    Private m_strComputerName As String
    Private m_strManufacturer As String
    Private m_StrModel As String
    Private m_strOSName As String
    Private m_strOSVersion As String
    Private m_strSystemType As String
    Private m_strTPM As String
    Private m_strWindowsDir As String


    Public Sub New()

        objOS = New ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_OperatingSystem")
        objCS = New ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_ComputerSystem")
        For Each objMgmt In objOS.Get


            m_strOSName = objMgmt("name").ToString()
            m_strOSVersion = objMgmt("version").ToString()
            m_strComputerName = objMgmt("csname").ToString()
            m_strWindowsDir = objMgmt("windowsdirectory").ToString()
        Next

        For Each objMgmt In objCS.Get
            m_strManufacturer = objMgmt("manufacturer").ToString()
            m_StrModel = objMgmt("model").ToString()
            m_strSystemType = objMgmt("systemtype").ToString
            m_strTPM = objMgmt("totalphysicalmemory").ToString()
        Next
    End Sub

    Public ReadOnly Property ComputerName()
        Get
            ComputerName = m_strComputerName
        End Get

    End Property
    Public ReadOnly Property Manufacturer()
        Get
            Manufacturer = m_strManufacturer
        End Get

    End Property
    Public ReadOnly Property Model()
        Get
            Model = m_StrModel
        End Get

    End Property
    Public ReadOnly Property OsName()
        Get
            OsName = m_strOSName
        End Get

    End Property

    Public ReadOnly Property OSVersion()
        Get
            OSVersion = m_strOSVersion
        End Get

    End Property
    Public ReadOnly Property SystemType()
        Get
            SystemType = m_strSystemType
        End Get

    End Property
    Public ReadOnly Property TotalPhysicalMemory()
        Get
            TotalPhysicalMemory = m_strTPM
        End Get

    End Property

    Public ReadOnly Property WindowsDirectory()
        Get
            WindowsDirectory = m_strWindowsDir
        End Get

    End Property

End Class
```

Any possibility to get a service tag from WMI ?  From the client side form I display values like so:

```
   Dim objWMI As New clsWMI()
        With objWMI
            Debug.WriteLine("Computer Name = " & .ComputerName)
            Me.Label1.Text = "Name: " & .ComputerName
            Debug.WriteLine("Computer Manufacturer = " & .Manufacturer)
            Me.Label2.Text = "Manufacturer: " & .Manufacturer
            Debug.WriteLine("Computer Model = " & .Model)
            Me.Label3.Text = "Model: " & .Model
            Debug.WriteLine("OS Name = " & .OsName)
            Me.Label4.Text = "OS Name: " & .OsName
            Debug.WriteLine("OS Version = " & .OSVersion)
            Me.Label5.Text = "OS VERSION: " & .OSVersion

            Debug.WriteLine("System Type = " & .SystemType)
            Me.Label6.Text = "System type = " & .SystemType

            Debug.WriteLine("Total Physical Memory = " & .TotalPhysicalMemory)
            Me.Label7.Text = "Memory: " & .TotalPhysicalMemory
            Debug.WriteLine("Windows Directory = " & .WindowsDirectory)
            Me.Label8.Text = "Win Directory: " & .WindowsDirectory
        End With
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to get the serial number from the BIOS like this:

```
Select SerialNumber From Win32_BIOS
```

On Dell's I believe this corresponds to the service tag

Comment: Hi Jason I did something like this:

 objS = New ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_SystemEnclosure")

Then I was able to pull the serial number like so:

        For Each objMgmt In objS.Get
            m_strSerial = objMgmt("serialnumber").ToString()
        Next

I guess my question is what is the different between WIN32_BIOS and Win32_SystemEnclosure ?  I even ran it on a rebuilt machine and it works...

Comment: From what i can tell, Win32_SsytemEnclosure is based on the physical box that the computer is built in, whereas Win32_BIOS is the chip on the motherboard. My theory is if you move a motherboard from its original case to another case, then the service tags you get from BIOS and SystemEnclosure might be different, but i have not tested this. It's probably safe to assume that the serial number from either class would be accurate.

Comment: Or use C# to call get this DOS output `wmic PATH WIN32_BIOS get SerialNumber /format:List`

Answer (score 1):

Here is some C# code that should get it

Here im getting from [Win32_ComputerSystem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394102(VS.85).aspx) but if you desire you can easly convert it to run againt [Win32_Bios](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394077(VS.85).aspx)

```
void GetComputerSystem()
{
        // http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394102(VS.85).aspx
        ManagementObjectCollection oReturnCollection;
        try
        {
            ObjectQuery query = new ObjectQuery("Select UserName,Name,Manufacturer,Model from Win32_ComputerSystem");
            ManagementObjectSearcher oSearcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(gManager, query);
            oReturnCollection = oSearcher.Get();
            oSearcher.Dispose();
        }
        catch
        {
            gHasError = true;
            return;
        }

        //loop through found drives and write out info
        foreach (ManagementObject oReturn in oReturnCollection)
        {
        // Disk name  
            object oLoggedInUser = oReturn["UserName"];
            if (oLoggedInUser == null)
                gOSInfo.UserName = "None";
            else
                gOSInfo.UserName = (string)oLoggedInUser;

            string Manufacturer = (string)oReturn["Manufacturer"];
            string Model = (string)oReturn["Model"];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: He is already doing that. None of the values you are querying relate to the service tag of the machine.

Comment: Jason I posted this above:

Hi Jason I did something like this: objS = New ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_SystemEnclosure") Then I was able to pull the serial number like so: For Each objMgmt In objS.Get m_strSerial = objMgmt("serialnumber").ToString() Next I guess my question is what is the different between WIN32_BIOS and Win32_SystemEnclosure ? I even ran it on a rebuilt machine and it works...

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a program the recovers the Dell Service Tag, Express Code and links to the Driver and Warranty information. You can find the C# code at

http://samuelhaddad.com/software-projects/dellservicetagfinder/

I hope this helps others.

Answer (score 0):

```
namespace Con2
{
    using System;
    using System.Management;
    using System.IO;

    class Program
    {
        public static string computerName = "localhost";

        // a central place to store the info, 
        public static string inventFile = @"\\Wdstorage\public\install\Inventfile.txt";

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(inventFile, FileMode.Append);

                if (File.Exists(inventFile))
                {
                    using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fileStream))
                    {
                        sw.Write("Added: " + DateTime.Now.ToString());

                        ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope(@"\\" + computerName + @"\root\cimv2");
                        scope.Connect();

                        ObjectQuery query = new ObjectQuery("Select * From Win32_SystemEnclosure");
                        ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, query);
                        ManagementObjectCollection objColl = searcher.Get();

                        foreach (ManagementObject o in objColl)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("ServiceTag=" + o["SerialNumber"].ToString());
                            sw.Write(",  ServiceTag=" + o["SerialNumber"].ToString());
                        }

                        query = new ObjectQuery("Select * from Win32_ComputerSystem");
                        searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, query);

                        objColl = searcher.Get();

                        foreach (ManagementObject oReturn in objColl)
                        {
                            string Manufacturer = (string)oReturn["Manufacturer"];
                            sw.Write(", Manufacturer=" + (string)oReturn["Manufacturer"]);

                            string Model = (string)oReturn["Model"];
                            sw.Write(", Model=" + (string)oReturn["Model"]);

                            string name = (string)oReturn["Name"];
                            sw.Write(", name=" + (string)oReturn["name"]);

                            string userName = (string)oReturn["UserName"];
                            sw.Write(", userName=" + (string)oReturn["userName"]);

                            Console.WriteLine((string)oReturn["Manufacturer"]);
                            Console.WriteLine((string)oReturn["Model"]);
                            Console.WriteLine((string)oReturn["Name"]);
                            Console.WriteLine((string)oReturn["UserName"]);

                        }
                        sw.WriteLine();
                        sw.Close();
                    }
                }
                // else 
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error :" + ex.Message );
                Console.WriteLine("Prova att köra programmet en gång till..");
            }

            Console.WriteLine("");
            Console.Write("<Enter> to quit :");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```