# how to make winform setup and deployment files only for one pc

Tags: c#, .net

When I deploy winform application on machine and copy application files from program file folder and run on anther machine it runs .how to prevent this?
I want to make setup that works for only one pc.
Is their any way to do so

Comment: Get it's MAC and check it before start

Comment: Normally you explicitly don't want that. If there is no technical reason, it should run on another computer. So I think, you are talking about some kind of licensing...

Comment: write  some pereferenece on registry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must ask yourself what describe this particural PC? Is it hardaware? or User? or enviroment?

When You do this You can calculate the right checksum of this one PC

You can use system register  with user name to calucultate checksum

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\ CurrentVersion\ProductId
```

is unique per machine/per windows install.

or simple some Environment varable like

```
Environment.UserDomainName

Environment.UserName

Environment.MachineName
```

Each position is some way very connect to one PC

Links:

[What is a good unique PC identifier?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3443093/what-is-a-good-unique-pc-identifier)

[What's a good way to uniquely identify a computer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/671876/whats-a-good-way-to-uniquely-identify-a-computer)

[Generating a unique machine id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/99880/generating-a-unique-machine-id)